# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory if save file in folder OneDrive

Tags: python, python-3.x, onedrive, errno

I get an error when trying to save data to a file, if everything is located in the OneDrive folder. If you move everything to another location, everything is saved, for example:
C:\Users\max\OneDrive\Documents\ - error
C:\Users\max\OneDrive\ - no error
The result is the same when starting from the administrator or turning off OneDrive. The folder is saved locally (it exists, you can see it when you output it)

```
with open("hello.txt", "w") as file:
    print("Hello world", file=file)
```

Comment: how are you executing the script?